# I have to remove the docker container every day before to starting

Tags: docker

I'm working an app that it has docker and every day I started the container with

docker run --env-file ..env -e REDIS_HOST=stredis -v C:\inetpub\einvoice-connect\src:/var/www/eic -p 443:8443 -d --name eicapp eic:latest

the problem is that the remote desktops is restarted every day, so I have to start the container again but when I want to start I got the message:

> docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name
> "/eicapp" is already in use by container
> "e4a36b85e15567ca1b69cf6de87e76d03ddee6aca069f74503601cd3d284c98c".
> You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that
> name.

So I have to remove the container, started again and config the container every day.

Is there a way to start the container without removed?

Comment: how about `docker run --rm`? What about just `docker run --restart always`?

Comment: any possiblilty to stop the container properly (`docker stop`) before restarting the remote desktop?

Comment: You can simply run `docker stop <container>` and `docker start <container>`. It will start the container with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the container, add the restart option `--restart` to your command:

```
docker run --restart=unless-stopped --env-file ..env -e REDIS_HOST=stredis -v C:\inetpub\einvoice-connect\src:/var/www/eic -p 443:8443 -d --name eicapp eic:latest
```

From the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart), `unless-stop` option means: "always restart the container regardless of the exit status, including on daemon startup, except if the container was put into a stopped state before the Docker daemon was stopped."

I suggest to use `--restart=unless-stopped` so you can keep track if something goes wrong. Othervise, if you use the `always` policy it keeps restarting forever regardless if errors happen.

Comment: If for some reason I have to stop the container and re-run again the docker run command, how can I start it without get the remove or rename container?

Comment: You can use `docker start <container-name>`. `Docker start` doesn't modify the container, but only restarts a stopped container moving it to the running state.

Comment: You should use `docker run` command only to create the contaienr the first time since it creates a new container, pulls the image and starts the container.

Comment: Now keep restarting after restar the host machine

Comment: This is what you asked in the initial question